# Transition-group inside v-for statement in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a `projects` object which I fill in after `axios` call. Then I'm looping though `projects` object using `v-for` directive. Here's code:

```
<ul class="row projects-list"> 
    <li v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
        @{{ project.project_name }} <br>
        <transition-group tag="ul" enter-active-class="animated fadeInUp" leave-active-class="animated fadeInDown">
            <li v-for="board in project.boards" :key="board.id">@{{ board.board_name }}</li>
        </transition-group>  
    </li>        
</ul>
```

Inside `projects` object I also have an object of objects called `boards` as you can see in the code above. My goal is that I want to animate a rendering of `boards` object. So, as a result I'm getting such errors:

> [Vue warn]: Property or method "project" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive, either in the data option, or for class-based components, by
>   initializing the property.

**and**

> [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'boards'
>   of undefined"

How to properly render my `transition-group`? What's the workaround?

**Here's a `Vue` instance:**

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        user: {!! Auth::user() !!},
        projects: {}
    },
    methods: {
        fetchProjects() {
            axios.get(`/api/projects/${this.user.id}`)
                .then((response) => {
                    if(response.status === 200) {
                        this.projects = response.data;
                        console.log(this.projects);
                    }
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.error(error);
                });
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchProjects();
    }
});
```

Comment: please share your all all related code ? specially about `projects` ?

Comment: @C2486 edited my question.

Comment: share your component `transition-group` Also ?

Comment: @C2486 it is built in vue js component.

Comment: I seems like component that why I gave you solution. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I'm looping though projects object using v-for directive.

If your "projects" is a object , the project in your case means projects attribute and you are foreach attributes of projects object.
According to your code, the projects and boards should be array, not object.

You should check if the response data: projects is an array first.

case I:

```
var objects = [{id:1,project_name:'aaa'},{id:2, project_name:'bbb'}]
```

result: aaa bbb

case II:

```
var objects = {attr1: {id:1, project_name:'aaa'}, attr2: {id:2, project_name:'bbb'}}
```

result: aaa bbb  (but the order is not guaranteed.)

Comment: I checked. They're all objects.

Answer (score 0):

All things replaced by vue.js inside component so you code for `<li>` is replace without any meaning. To make it work you need to pass `project` as `prop` to your component `transition-group`

```js
Vue.component('transition-group',{
 props:['project'],
 template:`<div>
     <li v-for="board in project.boards" :key="board.id">{{ board.board_name }}</li>
    </div>
  `
});

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        user: {name:'niklesh raut'},
        projects: []
    },
    methods: {
        fetchProjects() {
            this.projects = [{id:1,project_name:'test1',boards:[{id:11,board_name:'board_name11'}]},{id:2,project_name:'test2',boards:[{id:11,board_name:'board_name22'}]}]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.fetchProjects();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app" class="container-fluid">
    <ul class="row projects-list"> 
      <li v-for="project in projects" :key="project.id">
          {{ project.project_name }} <br>
          <transition-group :project="project" tag="ul" enter-active-class="animated fadeInUp" leave-active-class="animated fadeInDown">
        </transition-group>
      </li>        
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle for the same](http://jsfiddle.net/xcfjthbo/51/)