# How to implement <transition-group> inside a v-for loop?

Tags: vue.js, v-for, vuejs-transition-group

There's one suggested answer on this, but the solution isn't working for me. I have a nested `v-for` and would like to animate the innermost li elements as they are removed or added by my computed statement. My current code looks like so:

```html
    <transition-group @before-enter="beforeEnter" @enter="enter" @leave="leave" tag="ul" v-if="computedProviders">
      <li v-for="(letter, index) in computedProviders" :key="index">
        <div>
          <p>{{index.toUpperCase()}}</p>
        </div>
        <transition-group :letter="letter" tag="ul" class="list" @before-enter="beforeEnter" @enter="enter" @leave="leave">
          <li v-for="provider in letter" :key="provider.last_name">
            <div>
              <a :href="provider.permalink">
                {{provider.thumbnail}}
              </a>

              <div>
                <h3>
                  <a :href="provider.permalink">
                    {{provider.last_name}}, {{provider.first_name}} <span>{{provider.suffix}}</span><br>
                    <p>{{provider.specialty}}</p>
                  </a>
                </h3>
              </div>
            </div>
          </li>
        </transition-group>
      </li>
    </transition-group>
  </div>
```

The outer transition-group works fine, but when I set up the inner one I get

> ReferenceError: letter is not defined.

I tried adding `:letter="letter"` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49892865/transition-group-inside-v-for-statement-in-vue-js-2), but it's still not working for me. Any suggestions? I'm happy to reformat the code if there's a way that makes better sense.

Edit: in response to a couple of the comments here, first of all, I'm injecting Vue into a PHP-based Wordpress template, so I'm not able to create separate components. I don't know if that's part of what's causing the issue or why some of you can run the code with no errors.

Here's a sample of the JSON this is iterating over:

```
{
   a: [
       {
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Apple',
        suffix: 'DDS',
        permalink: 'www.test.com',
        thumbnail: '<img src="test.com" />',
        specialty: 'Some specialty'
       }, 
       {
        first_name: 'Jane',
        last_name: 'Apple',
        suffix: 'DDS',
        permalink: 'www.test.com',
        thumbnail: '<img src="test.com" />',
        specialty: 'Some specialty'
       }
      ],
    d: [
       {
        first_name: 'John',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        suffix: 'DDS',
        permalink: 'www.test.com',
        thumbnail: '<img src="test.com" />',
        specialty: 'Some specialty'
       }, 
       {
        first_name: 'Jane',
        last_name: 'Doe',
        suffix: 'DDS',
        permalink: 'www.test.com',
        thumbnail: '<img src="test.com" />',
        specialty: 'Some specialty'
       }
      ]
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code? It would be helpful to have an example of the data you are iterating over.

Comment: I've just tested your code and it seems to be working fine. What exactly is the problem you're facing?

Comment: Prefer maybe using the CSS properties`-in-enter`, `-in-leave-to`, `-move`, `-enter-active`, `-leave-active etc...` to have an easier time handling this kind of stuff. Will clutter a bit less your template.

Comment: @TUTAMKHAMON when I add the inner transition-group I get the ReferenceError: letter is not defined. As if it's unable to pass the letter prop through transition-group in the same way as it can a plain <ul>.

Comment: Your code works fine in this [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-germain-7jts2?file=/src/components/MyList.vue). Can you link to a reproduction?

Comment: @tony19 https://codepen.io/kslaton/pen/MWpYGyP . I'm injecting Vue into PHP, not using the framework. I believe this is contributing to the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the [caveats with using in-DOM templates](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats) is that the browser parses the DOM *before* Vue gets to it. The browser doesn't know what `<transition-group tag="ul">` is, so that just gets ignored. Instead, it sees an `<li>` inside another `<li>`. Since `<li>` elements normally cannot be nested, the browser hoists `<li v-for="provider in letter" :key="provider.last_name">` outside its parent `<li>` that defines `letter`.

[Removing Vue and inspecting the DOM](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/rNyaoWP?editors=1010) will reveal the problem:

[image: hoisted DOM]

When Vue processes that template, it encounters `letter`, which is technically undeclared outside of the `v-for`, resulting in the error you're seeing.

### Solution 1: `<template>` wrapper

If you need to use in-DOM templates, wrap the inner `<transition-group>` with a `<template>` so that the browser will ignore it:

```html
<transition-group tag="ul">
  <li v-for="(letter, index) in computedProviders" :key="index">
    <template> 
      <transition-group tag="ul">
        <li v-for="provider in letter" :key="provider.last_name"></li>
      </transition-group>
    </template>
  </li>
</transition-group>
```

[demo 1](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/eYvmbmP?editors=1010)

### Solution 2: String templates

Move the template into a string (using the [`template` option](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#template)), which avoids the DOM parsing caveats:

```js
new Vue({
  template: 
    `<transition-group tag="ul">
       <li v-for="(letter, index) in computedProviders" :key="index">
         <transition-group tag="ul">
           <li v-for="provider in letter" :key="provider.last_name"></li>
         </transition-group>
       </li>
     </transition-group>`
  //...
}).$mount('#providers')
```

[demo 2](https://codepen.io/tony19/pen/poevqaQ?editors=1010)

Comment: this did it for me, thanks! the bounty expired before I got to this answer but I'll try and figure out how to award it to you.

Comment: @kdsprogrammer Happy to help

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know what's causing the error, but try creating a new component that accepts `letter` as a prop and contains your inner `<transition-group>`. Then embed this new component in your root `v-for`.

It should give something like that:

```html
<transition-group @before-enter="beforeEnter" @enter="enter" @leave="leave" tag="ul" v-if="computedProviders">
  <li v-for="(letter, index) in computedProviders" :key="index">
    <div>
      <p>{{index.toUpperCase()}}</p>
    </div>
    <my-component :letter="letter" />
  </li>
</transition-group>
```

Comment: I'm injecting Vue into PHP, this isn't built on a Vue template, so I can't create separate components.